# Why is there an Error showed "you already own this item" when successfully redeem a promo code for IAB purchase in Google for Android App

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, promotion-code

I was testing In App Billing Purchase in my app, I have already published my app to Google Console through Beta closed test, and then I found that when I choose option "Redeem code", and actually input the promo code generate by Google, there is always an Error showed by Google, says "You already own this item".

I use the exactly same code as sample TrivialDrive provided by Google only change to my package etc. and also, if I choose debit card or paypal, no error showed.

> NOTE: I use a new cell phone with a new register account, this
>   behavior CAN ACTUALLY buy the IAB product, in my code I can also
>   consume it and update UI, it's just always this error showed, and I
>   think it's really annoying to user any one has a solution?

[Error looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4llE.jpg)